# Add a "Reload This Page" button on Front End

Tags: magento-1.9, 404, 404-page

for some reason our product pages like to redirect to the 404 page not found every now and again but this is usually resolved by refreshing the page.

Unfortunately not everybody is going to know this and the only current option we have is a hyperlink/button for "Return to Home Page" which obviously isn't ideal and unnecessarily lengthens the customer journey.

Is there a way to add a "Refresh/Reload This Page" in to the CMS page?

Preferably in a way I can add it using the wysiwyg or html as i'm not clued up on Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way, `Admin->CMS->Page->` then select `no-route` as URL key page, then add this:

```
<p><button id="refresh">Refresh</button></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    jQuery('#refresh').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go when I get a chance! Is there anything I can add to that which will dictate the size / dimensions of the button?